# how put my login with diferent user levels in angular

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

how i put my login with diffent user level like this
if level its 1 the user its superadmin if its 2 the user its administrator
and if its 3 its employs
i using angular 7 nodejs and mongodb
this is link to my project https://github.com/Kammikazy/project

this is my code

auth file
       getUserDetails(username,password){
    return this.http.post('api/login',{
    username,
    password
    })
    }

login component

```
login() {
      let username = this.loginForm.value.username;
         let password = this.loginForm.value.password;
      this.Auth.getUserDetails(username,password).subscribe(data =>{
        if(data.success){
      this.router.navigate(['homepage'])
      this.Auth.setLoggedIn(true)
      //sdsadad
        }else{
        document.getElementById("erro").style.visibility = "visible";
        window.setTimeout("location.href='login'",3000);

        }
      })

      }

nodejs

    app.post('/api/login', async (req,res)=>{
      const {username,password}=req.body
      const resp = await User.findOne({ username: username}).select('+password')
      if(password==null){
        res.json({success:false,
          message:"  password can not be empty"
        })
      }else if(username==null){
        res.json({success:false,
          message:" username can not be empty "
        })
      }
      else if(!resp){
        res.json({success:false,
          message:"incorrect password"
        })

      }
      else if(!await bcrypt.compare(password, resp.password)){
    //if(!resp){

      res.json({success:false,
        message:"incorrect password"
      })
    }else {
      ///sessions
      req.session.user=username
      req.session.save()

      res.json({
        success:true
      })

    }
    })
```

Comment: did you want to navigate  the user with the specific role ?

Comment: you should store role in a string and then simply check  using if after subscribed

Comment: yes i want navigete the user with specific role what i have to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  // declare golbal variable
responce: any;
login() {
  let username = this.loginForm.value.username;
  let password = this.loginForm.value.password;
  this.Auth.getUserDetails(username, password).subscribe(data => {
    this.responce = data
    if (this.responce.user == 'level1') {
      this.router.navigate(['homepage'])
      this.Auth.setLoggedIn(true)
      //sdsadad

    } else if (this.responce.user == 'level2') {

      this.router.navigate(['secondpage'])
    }
    else if (this.responce.user == 'level3') {

      this.router.navigate(['thirdpage'])
    }

  })
}
```

Comment: its not working  this is the link to my project https://github.com/Kammikazy/project what i doing wrong

Comment: you are not storing the response in a global variable and so far you are not comparing user role string value because maybe you didn't declare role of user's

Comment: how i do that i new using angular  i storing all data in mongodb

Comment: simply store user role in a string variable and send along the data you are storing while creating user . 
For Example: A user is entering values for signup at that time decide whether the user  is at level 1 or level 2 or 3 level.

Comment: thanks i find the soluction to make my login with levels of acess  now i have other problem i want use the same page but i want have differents menu in same page one superadmin other to admin and other to the employs

Comment: simply show content to the specific user.
make three different menus and show the specific menu to the relative user.
Example:  
      <div *ngIf ="user.role=='admin'">consider this div as your menu </div>
      <div *ngIf ="user.role=='superadmin'">consider this div as your menu </div>

Comment: i all ready have find the soluction but thanks for the help have good day our night and have a good work if you area working  Muhammad Abdullah